# How to make intellij idea prefer one git remote over another when I push a new branch?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

In most of my  projects I have a main repo and my fork. In the team we follow the PR process, so in order to make a change it needs to push a change into the fork repo and then create a PR  in the main repo. I personally prefer working in feature branches rather than master.
So my usual scenario is like that:

1. Create a feature branch
2. Make a change
3. Push the feature branch into my fork
4. Create RP, etc...

I love git client in intellij, but one thing is almost driving me nuts.
When I push a new branch, it shows a Push dialog and selects a remote repo. Sometimes it is my fork, sometimes it is the main repo. I wish I can tell Intellij to always  stick to my fork.
[image]
Does anybody know how to make Intellij choose one remote over another?
Some examples of potential solutions that solve my problem(none of them exists, or I didn't find how to enable):

1. A project setting "use this repo to push new branches to by default"
2. A project setting "never push a new branch here". Like they do for protected branches.
3. Have remote list sorted alphabetically or somehow else and pick the first/last from the list. This way I could rename my remote to make it first/last.
4. Have a special name for a favorite remote. Like if I have a remote named 'push_here_please', then Idea will choose it by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in a behavior of the dialog.

I have created an ticket on YouTrack, please feel free to vote:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-287414

Comment: Thank you!
I see in the ticket description it is said it gives a preference to a remote called `origin`.  I hope they implement a general order, but at least it sounds like a workaround for me.